# select subclass of the subclass css

Tags: html, css

I would like to set special css for the **"This is paragraph 1"** and all other titles another one. How to do it ?

```html
<div class="example2">
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
        This is paragraph 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
        This is paragraph 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
        This is paragraph 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I was trying this but doesn't work. How to reach first ***".goal"*** class in css ?

```css
div.example2 p.special p.goal { color: green; }
div.example2 p.special p.goal ~ p.goal { color: #333; }
```

Comment: Be sure to actually use paragraph elements for paragraphs. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first write a style for all div then override by using `:first-child` selector.

```css
.example2 > .special { color: #333; }

.example2 > .special:first-child { color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="example2">
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
        This is paragraph 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
        This is paragraph 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
        This is paragraph 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to style the first item, style them all and override the first:

```css
.goal {
  color: orange;
}

.special:first-child .goal {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="example2">
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
      This is paragraph 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
      This is paragraph 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
      This is paragraph 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could go the other way...

```css
.goal {
  color: green;
}

.special:not(:first-child) .goal {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="example2">
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
      This is paragraph 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
      This is paragraph 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="special">
    <div class="goal">
      This is paragraph 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```